# Google analytics outbound link tracking not working in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to get React Google Analytics to recognize an outbound link click, but when I click on the link I have setup and check the data in the Google admin console the link is not recognized.

I signed up and got a tracking id from the Google site. I then created an Analytics.js file which looks like the following:

```
import ReactGA from 'react-ga'

export const initGA = () => {
    console.log('GA init')
    ReactGA.initialize('MY TRACKING ID IS HERE')
}

export const logPageView = () => {
    console.log(`Loggin pageview for ${window.location.pathname}`)
    ReactGA.set({ page: window.location.pathname })
    ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname)
}
```

Then in the App.js file I added the correct syntax for the outbound link:

```
    <div>
      <ReactGA.OutboundLink
          eventLabel="myLabel"
          to="http://www.example.com"
          target="_blank">
          My Link
        </ReactGA.OutboundLink>
    </div>
```

I also added: import ReactGA from 'react-ga'

However, after clicking on the link multiple times, Google still does not recognize the link being clicked. How can I get Google Analytics to recognize the link being clicked from my React component? The only thing I have thought is that it is either because I am running on Localhost or I have not properly initialized ReactGA. I greatly appreciate help.

Comment: For testing use the Analytics Debug js on your localhost. Debug prints in console EVERYTHING is doing, including firing events.

Comment: Also just to confirm. Is the URL opening or is blocked and are you verifying event in real time reports?

Comment: i got it working. i just wasn't initializing GA properly. thanks for your help!